# javascript not a constructor exception while creating objects in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am facing any issue in react.
Here How I am defining the class `BackendServiceClient`

```
class BackendServiceClient {
  private readonly source: string;

constructor(source?: string) {
    if (source) {
      this.source = source;
    }
    axios.defaults.headers = this.setDefaultHeaders();
  }
}
.... some logic

export default BackendServiceClient;
```

This how the BackendServiceClient is export in `index.ts` in common library in this class we export all the vars that could be used by clients of the library

```
export { default as BackendServiceClient} from './api/BackendServiceClient';
```

While building this commons library into my application I got error
`commons.BackendServiceClient is not constructor`

and when checked the line causing errors from file  in node modules

```
backendServiceClient: /*#__PURE__*/new commons.BackendServiceClient(),
```

Does someone have faced this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: you should `import x from 'y'`. not export

Comment: @Omri Attiya

in `index.ts` we need to export this variables to the client of the commons libraries

Comment: what is `commons`? can you elaborate about it?

Comment: let consider it as `X library`  in `X library` base code we we add `backendServiceClient.ts` class  and  add `index.ts` file where we export the variables that could be used by external clients who add/use   `X library` into their `package.json`  into their application 
Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you export `BackendServiceClient` from *BackendServiceClient.ts*, when you want to use it in another file (let's say *index.ts*) you need to **`import`** it and then `export` it.

```
import BackendServiceClient from './api/BackendServiceClient';
```

And use it -

```
let backend = new BackendServiceClient();
```

Only then, export it -

```
export const client = {
    backend: backend
}
```

Comment: In `index.ts` file we aren't using BackendServiceClient
We only need to export it to be able to be used by the clients of the library

Answer (score 0):

After replicating your setup locally, you may want to ensure that you're importing `commons` correctly.

The solution that worked for me:

```
import * as commons from './<path_to_common_lib>';
new commons.BackendServiceClient();
```

If this doesn't help, verify your common library is not overwriting `BackendServiceClient` to something that's not a constructor.

(used TypeScript 4.8.3 and `ts-node@10.9.1`, all default settings)